# Intel HD Graphics vs NVIDIA Quadro FX 380 PCI-E

Tags: intel-graphics, nvidia-quadro, acer-veriton

I recently purchased an Acer Veriton which has an i5-650 processor, Windows 7 Pro (64 bit) and Intel HD Graphics listed as the video card.  I also purchased a PNY nVIDIA Quadro FX 380 PCI-E card for improved picture and home video viewing and editing.
I have already replaced the original 300 wattt power supply to a 430 watt Antec Truepower I had on hand and boosted the RAM to 8 gigs from the original 4.

Question 1) Am I getting any improvement in visual quality or system speed with the Quadro or is it a waste of money and I should just save up to buy a bigger video card? This card was on sale for $115.

If I am getting improvement then I need to ask another question.

Question 2) Instructions for the Quadro installation are as follows...

1--Uninstall the existing VGA driver.
-Remove the existing Display Driver via "Add or Remove Porgrams".
-Shut down your computer.

2--Remove your Existing Graphics Board (or Disable Integrated 3D Graphics Controller).

**skipping instructions on how to remove existing graphics board**

-Systems with integrated (also know as on-board) 3D graphics may require you to disable the integrated 3D graphics system.  Consult the owners or vendor manual that came with your PC on how to properly do this.

So is the Intel HD Graphics considered a 3D graphics controller?  If so should I just contact Acer or can anyone give me instructions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Quadro FX is for CAD and professional graphics. But of course, you get improvements. Intel HD is for basic graphics, for the needs of a single user with Firefox, family home movies and such. You can play with a Quadro, but it's best use is CAD, Photoshop, etc.

(But yeah it worth it anyway.)

For your questions:
- Intel is integrated. You don't remove it. Just install the new card, open the BIOS menu, and switch to external VGA. Look for such option. THEN, remove the Intel video driver. Reboot, install NVidia. That's all. The OS will boot with the new card just fine. Windows checks for new hardware.. oh new VGA..will install basic NVidia drivers to basic usage at first boot with the new card.. and then do what I wrote.

(If you ask me, it worth the change.)

Comment: Thanks!  The main reason I had gotten the card was for the video editing and for my wife who is an amateur photographer and uses Photoshop Elements. I hope to eventually get back into gaming when my kids get a bit older and this can limp me through until I can buy a serious gaming PC.

Comment: Hmm. CLick on the "Comparison" button> http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-FX-380M.24737.0.html As you can see its not a powerhouse when it comes to gaming. However, if you dont want to game in FullHD, its pretty enough. My HD3650 can run COD MW2 totally fine in 1280x800.